# How to access browser javascript APIs from another browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to access one browser javascript APIs from another browser.

For example, if I am writing chrome extensions, is there any way to access javascript API for Firefox browser (let us say, History API for Firefox) installed on the same machine?

I looked at the [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) in mdn, but it doesn't seem to satisfy my requirement.

> Is it possible that extensions written for one browser communicate with extension for another browser?

For example, if I write a chrome extensions, can I communicate with Firefox add-on from it?

> If it is not possible to have communication between extensions/browsers, how come Chrome/Firefox able to pull our
>    settings,bookmarks etc,. from another browser when we first install
>    it?

Any help?

Comment: `how come Chrome/Firefox able to pull our settings,bookmarks etc,. from another browser` - because the browser can do that - there's no reason an addon should be able to have such far reaching access **at all**

Comment: You can't do that directly. You can write a native OS utility that communicates via nativeMessaging API with both extensions you'll need to write for each browser. The utility may be written in js if you don't mind having node.js or electron installed.